# React input value getting reset to initial state after onChange callback

Tags: reactjs

I am having an issue where I have an input to update based a user editing the current value. However, the value gets set back to its initial state value after the user types in a new value.

I have put a debug point in my code and see that my `onChange` callback handler is properly setting the `state` and shows the changed value in my input field. However, some event seems to change it back.

Here is my component:

```
class UserFields extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user:props.user
        };
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }
    render() {
        const user = this.state.user;
        return (
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="user-first-name">First name</label>
                    <input name="FirstName" type="text" value={user.FirstName} onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        className="form-control" id="user-first-name" placeholder="First name" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="user-last-name">Last name</label>
                    <input name="LastName" type="text" value={user.LastName} onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        className="form-control" id="user-last-name" placeholder="Last name" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="user-active">Active</label>
                    <input name="Active" id="user-active" type="checkbox" checked={user.Active} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

I have seen multiple questions that are similar to this one explaining to `setState` on my value with the `onChange` callback function. However, they do not seem to fix my issue. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 3):

Your `value` for (for example) the FirstName is `this.state.user.FirstName`.

In your `onChange` handler you are not modifying `this.state.user`. You are modifying something else entirely (`this.[name]`?).

In your handler you need to take the old user and create a new user with the proper field modified (I suggest `Object.assign`). Then you call `this.setState({user: myNewUserObject})`

Note that this kind of state handling in leaf components can lead to unintuitive behavior. I strongly suggest storing your state on the upper level (propagating the handler method inside `props`) in case you ever need to f.ex. make an AJAX call with the input data.

Comment: Ah i cant believe i missed it... must have been the product of a late night. In any event, thank you! Question on your AJAX comment though... Why cant i make an AJAX call from within the component?

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the wrong value. You are using the default values the whole time. Change it from

```
value={user.FirstName}
```

to

```
value={this.state.FirstName ? this.state.FirstName : user.FirstName }
```

And so on.